# How to perform an action at a certain time with NSTimer?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimer, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to perform an action at a certain time of the day.

I don't want to use `UILocalNotification` as I don't want the users to be away if anything is happening.

My current code is:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(fire:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Comment: Please show what you're doing with the web socket and how that comes into play here. I for one don't know what you mean by "using a web socket" and how that relates to the code line you posted about setting a timer to fire. Need more details on what you're doing, and what specifically about that isn't working. (That is, to debug what you have, vs offering a different solution; I don't have a solution of my own to offer, but maybe can see something amiss with the code you're using...)

Comment: I'm sorry, but how can this help people give me an answer? All i'm looking for is a way to perform and action at a certain time. 'Using web sockets' has nothing to do with the answer. If you want to check out my websocket, have a look at SocketRocket.

Comment: Thanks Bill Patterson :)

Comment: Ya know, nevermind. Sorry I couldn't help you.

Comment: Here's your ninja edit :D "The fake politeness is so endearing. 'luv you too! :-)" Thanks anyway bill, i just found it weird that a stranger was asking for my code that has no relevance to the question whatsoever, I shouldn't have mentioned websockets.

Comment: Yah, sorry. I edited that because I realized it was an asshole thing to say and I regretted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

1. Extract the current local time each time your app starts using `[NSDate date]` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.
2. Calculate the time left for your *alarm time* to occur using `dateWithTimeInterval:sinceDate`.
3. Start a `NSTimer` with `interval = that_time_difference`.

I'm not sure what do you mean by:

> "I don't want the users to be away of anything happening."

I am assuming you don't want anything to happen if the app is not running. The only thing I can think of would be push notifications.

Comment: Hey Dsaw, I did it this way, the actions are about 10ms now, maybe this is due to using the simulator and my iPhone. What I did was, send a timestamp with my message from the server. Then on my device, I calculate the local timestamp, then compare those two and set the difference as my delay. I'm not sure how to do part b) in your solution, would you be able to clarify on it please? Sorry, i'm a total noob at all of this

Comment: b) is finding the time difference.
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *actionDate = [NSDate dateWithString:@"..."]; //timestamp_from_server
CGFloat timeDiff = [actionDate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeDiff target:self selector:@selector(fire:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];